# i want to open my destination fragment by clicking on notification but the main activity opens

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

here is my code

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nevgraph)
            .setDestination(R.id.playmusic)
            .createPendingIntent();
    NotificationManager manager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification= new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,channelID)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
 .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)
                    .setMediaSession(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.getMediaSession(new Notification())))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build();
```

i want to open the playmusic fragment on click of notification .

Comment: You can not directly load the fragment while clicking on the notification so you need to redirect user to the respective activity and pass a flag in that to open certain fragment in that activity.